# Ghost script changing dimensions of the input pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, eps

I am using gs 9.20 and trying to generate eps file using below command from a pdf file.

```
gs -q -dNOCACHE -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=tempEpsFile.eps tempCmykPdfFile.pdf
```

Now the problem is that eps file is getting generated successfully but the dimension of the generated eps file different from the pdf file.

[image]

The area outside the content area (gray color) is white space.

The PDF consist of standard Area, while the eps file generated is contains only the content area.
Attaching the pdf and eps image screenshot

PDF: here dimension is in points (Screen shot from Adobe Illustrator)

[image]

EPS:  here dimension is in points (Screen shot from Adobe Illustrator)

[image]

I am not sure why its happening or how to resolve it.

Below is the output of `pdfinfo -box` command on the pdf file.

```
  $pdfinfo -box tempCmykPdfFile.pdf
   Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.20
   CreationDate:   Tue Mar  7 09:48:56 2017
   ModDate:        Tue Mar  7 09:48:56 2017
   Tagged:         no
   Pages:          1
   Encrypted:      no
   Page size:      212.6 x 113.39 pts
   MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
   CropBox:            0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
   BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
   TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
   ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
   File size:      20886 bytes
   Optimized:      no
   PDF version:    1.5
```

Also, output of `gs -sDevice=bbox`

```
   %%BoundingBox: 14 48 199 100
```

To summarize the problem: `pdf` has the page size of  `212.6 x 113.39 pts` while for the generated `eps` Page size is : `576x 792 pts`. If we look from the first image then the Sandard Area is getting changed while the Content Area remain same

Comment: _"the generated eps Page size is : 576x 792 pts"_ No. There's no such thing as "eps Page size". What you observe is **your own last choice** with totally different file you made in Illustrator after doing ctrl-N + OK. OTOH, Illustrator-made EPS files **pretend** to have a "page size" because they attach native AI file to EPS as a comment. For EPS BoundingBox to be equal to PDF MediaBox, -- see KenS' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the input file at the very least to be able to comment, but the most likely explanation is that the original PDF file has both a MediaBox and a CropBox. Ghostscript defaults to using the MediaBox (and that's what will get emitted in the EPS) while Acrobat defaults to using the CropBox.

Put the input file somewhere, and post the URL here and I can take a look at it.

Note; EPS files are intended for inclusion in other documents, thus the BoundingBox of an EPS file is defined as the smallest rectangle which includes all the marks made by the EPS program. So, when generating an EPS file, its perfectly correct for eps2write to create an EPS where the BoundingBox only includes the area of the marks, and does **not** include any white space. If you want white space around it, you should add that in the enclosing document.

Comment: Hi @KenS, Thanks for the reply. I am afraid I won't be in position to share the file. But, I have added some more info w.r.t to MediaBox and CropBox, let me know if that helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: Well if you can't share the file then there is nothing more I can say. The output of pdfinfo and the bbox device doesn't tell me anything useful and you still haven't described your actual problem.

Comment: My problem is that the `pdf` Page size  is:  212.6 x 113.39 pts while for the generated `eps`  Page size : 576x 792 pts.                                                                      If we look from the first image then the `Sandard Area` is getting changed while the `Content Area` remain same.